# AWS pass large number of ENV variables into codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

Currently our singleton application including 5 containers goes through AWS `pipeline` into `code build` and then code deploy into ECS services. During codebuild base on an ENV set in codebuild  `$Stage` it can be `dev, prod or staging` and loads a specific config file for which contains all the ENV variables each container needs. See below:

```
build:
commands:
  #Get commit id
  - "echo STAGE $STAGE"
  - "export STAGE=$STAGE"
  #Assigning AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY needs to be done in two steps, otherwise it ends up in "Partial credentials found in env" error
  - "export ANSIBLE_VARS=\"\
        USE_EXISTING_VPC=true \
        DISABLE_BASIC_AUTH=true\""
  - "export DOCKER_ARGS=\"-e COMMIT_ID=$GIT_COMMIT -e APP_ENV=$STAGE
```

**Problem 1**: is these config files are within the repo and anybody can modify them. So there are lots of human errors like the production redirect Url is pointing to the wrong place, or new ENV is not set.

So I want to move away from loading different config files and move ENV variables to AWS to handle. Something like  during code build it will load from `parameter store`. Is this correct way?

**Problem 2** is there are lots of ENV variables, is the only option to list them one by one in the CloudFormation template ? Are there any other better way to load all of ENV variable into `DOCKER_ARG` from above build command ?

Comment: In general, you should only build one image to be deployed to multiple environments. Config differences should be set at runtime, not build time.

Comment: @jordanm that is what I thought too, but somehow especially frontend seems to be loading a bunch of ENV variables during build time. I don't know if its using webpack has anything to do with it. Also let's say I manager to load everything at runtime, the only way is still to write every single Env variable in CF template right ?

Comment: I would indeed use the Parameter Store String List containing the Env Variables, use the AWS CDK oder a simple “pre-processor” stage with bash to insert all of you variables into the CF template before deploying it. Cloudformation does a good job in separating duties, it has no procedural conponents like for/while in it, for those dynamic topics the CDK is great in my oppinion.